# Move up View when keyboard appears, but only for device X

Tags: ios, swift

I wasn't able to find a solution here for my problem which seems to be just that little step above the regular *"move up view when keyboard appears"* thing.

Although this is exactly what I need I want this **only** to happen on an iPhone 5S or iPhone SE.

So I've got the following code so far which is working fine with iOS 11:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide() {
    self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
}

@objc func keyboardWillChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if myTextField.isFirstResponder {
            self.view.frame.origin.y = -keyboardSize.height
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried several things to put this into an if case and I've searched for how to define things only for types of devices but as a beginner (6th week learning...) I've totally failed so far.

Comment: FYI - Don't do anything based on the specific device. Make your decisions based on view size.

Comment: wait... what? I've just added a constant "let screenHeight = view!.bounds.height" and put the viewDidLoad part into "if screenHeight <= 570..." and that just did the job. That's all? Thank you, @maddy!

Answer (score -1):

After @rmaddy gave me the right hint I'm giving the answer myself. All I did was adding an if case checking the view size with `view.bounds.height` (which is 568pt for an iPhone 5).

So the above code was changed to:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

let screenHeight = view!.bounds.height
//Checking the view size in pt here

if screenHeight <= 568 {
//add this to perform only for devices with view size 568 or lower
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide() {
    self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
}

@objc func keyboardWillChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if myTextField.isFirstResponder {
            self.view.frame.origin.y = -keyboardSize.height
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that's not right either. Your code should be checking to see whether the keyboard will cover the text field - plain and simple. If it does, do something to show the text field.

Comment: Hi @matt, that‘d be a great solution indeed. I didn‘t come across this, yet. Started to learn 5/6 weeks ago and there‘re many things left to learn. I‘ll get there some day. For now this worked for me because I knew only the iPhone 5S had that problem. Thank you for your comment. I‘ll keep that in mind.